# Do PCI Express devices' interrupts always go through a PIC or an APIC?

Tags: interrupts, computer-architecture, pcie, pci

My Question is `PCI`/`PCIe` interrupt path to CPU is through a PIC or an APIC?
[https://people.freebsd.org/~jhb/papers/bsdcan/2007/article/node4.html](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Ejhb/papers/bsdcan/2007/article/node4.html) shows there is a `PIR` which sits in between a `PIC` and `CPU`. If that is the case, how does an MSI(/MSI-X) works? My understanding is that MSI-X doesn't use a separate interrupt line, it uses the data path itself. In that case the `PCI` interrupt(MSI) bypasses `PIC` and talks to `CPU` over the `PCI`'s slot directly?

Comment: Are you designing a PCIe device or an operating system or what?

Comment: The exact implementation can vary pretty widely depending on the architecture. But typically the PCI controller is a self-contained component, and when it receives a TLP indicating an MSI/MSI-X signal, it will then signal its own interrupt line to the CPU (yes, usually, but not necessarily, via an interrupt controller). The CPU will then read some standard registers in the PCI controller to get information about what device signaled the MSI/MSI-X, etc. I'm not posting this as an answer because it's necessarily vague since no architecture was specified.

Comment: @TypeIA, Take the example of a Intel Xeon-x86_64 processor.